# How to show and hide the element attribute based on boolean value in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**ctrl.js**

In controller the value is true if user is landing on edit page

```
var self = this;
self.edit = "true"
```

**html**

On add page it should be

```
<md-input-container flex="25">
<label>GameId</label>
<input name="games" ng-model="ctrl.game" ng-required="true" ng-maxlength="50" custome-directive-to-check-unique-value >
</md-input-container>
```

On edit page it should be

```
<md-input-container flex="25">
<label>GameId</label>
<input name="games" ng-model="ctrl.game" ng-required="true" ng-maxlength="50" disabled>
</md-input-container>
```

For disable I can use `ng-disabled=ctrl.edit` to make input field disabled how, to do for directive  `custome-directive-to-check-unique-value`

Comment: self.edit = "true" ? as string , or boolean

Comment: It is a boolean field and its working fine just need how to remove custom directive .. able to do the field disabled perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the attribute `ng-show` or `ng-hide` based on the value.

```
<div ng-hide="edit">Edit is False</div>

<div ng-show="edit">Edit is True</div>
```

If edit is true then the ng-show would be true showing the message `Edit is True`

Comment: The field has to be there can't hide .. however on submit validation it is not allowing to submit. so only option is to remove that validation on edit condition

Comment: Your question `How to show and hide the element attribute based on boolean value in angularjs?` has been answered. I'm not sure what else you are asking specificity?

Comment: Not place the custom directive on both edited and add page, the custom directive can then check if the field is disabled, then don't run it's code

Answer (score 1):

You can use two input fields and use `ng-if` to show one of the fields based on a bool value which specify whether it is add view or edit view.

```
<input ng-if="!ctrl.edit" name="games" ng-model="ctrl.game" ng-required="true" ng-maxlength="50" custome-directive-to-check-unique-value  >
<input ng-if="ctrl.edit" name="games" ng-model="ctrl.game" ng-required="true" ng-maxlength="50" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use `ng-disabled`  directive to disable or enable your input text, but as i see you have done this already.

   2. As for the directive disable, why dont you use an if statement inside your directive body and check what you need to do according to your `ctrl.edit` value.

to do this just pass the `ctrl.edit` from your input text to your directive like this:

**html**

```
<input name="games" ng-model="ctrl.game" ng-required="true" ng-maxlength="50" custome-directive-to-check-unique-value   myFlag = "ctrl.edit">
```

**directive**

```
.directive('customeDirectiveToCheckUniqueValue', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                scope:{
                   myFlag :'='
                 },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    //here make your condition and add your code accordingly
                    if(myFlag){
                       //if true your code
                    }else{
                       //if false your code
                     }
                }
            };
        })
```

hope helps,good luck.